# HttpClient configuration

Tags: java, kotlin, http, web, reactor-netty

I was refactoring some old code the other day and came across a WebClient creation. (The code is written in Kotlin)

```kotlin
fun String.createClient(responseFilter: ExchangeFilterFunction = ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor { Mono.just(it) }): WebClient =
    WebClient
        .builder()
        .codecs {
            it.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(52428800) // 50 Mb
            it.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(jackson2JsonEncoder())
            it.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(jackson2JsonDecoder())
        }
        .baseUrl(this)
        .filter(responseFilter)
        .clientConnector(
            ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                HttpClient.create()
                    .tcpConfiguration {
                        it.bootstrap { b ->

                            b.setCustomRequestLogging {
                                b
                                    .group(onClient(DEFAULT_NATIVE))
                                    .channel(EpollSocketChannel::class.java)
                            }

                            updateLogSupport(b, CustomLoggingHandler(HttpClient::class.java))
                        }
                    }
                    .apply {
                        if (this@createClient.startsWith("https://", true))
                            secure { it.sslContext(SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(INSTANCE).build()) }
                    }
            )
        )
        .build()

fun <B : AbstractBootstrap<B, C>, C : Channel> AbstractBootstrap<B, C>.setCustomRequestLogging(init: HttpResources.() -> Unit) {

    if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase() == "linux" && config().group() == null)
        HttpResources.get().init()
}
```

Since `tcpConfiguration` and `bootstrap` are both marked deprecated I figured out I can replace it with

```kotlin
HttpClient.create().doOnRequest { _, connection -> connection.addHandlerFirst(CustomLoggingHandler(HttpClient::class.java)) }
```

but I'm not quite sure what's going on in this part

```kotlin
b.setCustomRequestLogging {
                                b
                                    .group(onClient(DEFAULT_NATIVE))
                                    .channel(EpollSocketChannel::class.java)
                            }
```

and how can I replace it using not deprecated api?

Answer (score 0):

By default when you are running on Linux OS, Reactor Netty will configure for you Epoll transport. There is no need to configure by yourself neither the channel type nor the `EventLoopGroup`.
For the deprecated `tcpConfiguration` check the javadoc for [HttpClient.html#tcpConfiguration](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient.html#tcpConfiguration-java.util.function.Function-) where you can find a complete documentation for the replacements.